# Tricky SQL Count (I think)

Tags: sql

Been trying all the examples and help from others that people have been posting.

Can't get it too work.

Basically I have

These fields and variables

```
[REF], [STATUS], [DATE], [Manager]
1       Review    121220   George
2       Closed    121220   George
2       Closed    122200   George
```

I want the output to give me the reference # and the amount of times it was closed so I can join onto another dataset.

so

```
REF TimesClosed
1       NULL/0 
2       2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Use a case expression to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself.

Comment: "Can't get it too work" is not a problem description. Show what you tried, and explain why it didn't work and/or what errors you got. Also, [edit] your post to tag which SQL implementation you are using; while it may not matter much in this case, it's good practice.

Answer (score 3):

This is only tricky because you cannot filter in the `WHERE` clause -- otherwise the row you want would not be in the result set.

So, use conditional aggregation:

```
select ref, sum(case when status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from t
group by ref;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only need a summary of closures, then you might be able to avoid using a `CASE` expression, e.g.

```
SELECT ref, COUNT(*) AS closed_cnt
FROM yourTable
WHERE [STATUS] = 'Closed'
GROUP BY ref;
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be go with `case` expression with `sum()`

```
select REF, sum(case when STATUS = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) TimesClosed
from table t
group by REF
```